# Page looks sparse, space between paragraph is too big (KOMA-Script)

Tags: koma-script, paragraphs, parskip

This page looks very sparse, LaTeX inserts way too much space between the paragraphs.

I use `\documentclass[paper=a4,twoside,parskip=half,12pt]{scrartcl}` for a short manual.

I would not mind if the page ended earlier, but I don't want to insert `\newpage` manually (content above may change).

Can I set a maximum inter-paragraph space or increase some penalty value?

Hint: There is a longer table on the next side. Please comment if you need a list of all my included packges too.

[image: Sparse-looking page with paragraphs]

Comment: Did you try the directive `\raggedbottom`  in your preamble?

Comment: Thank you. `\raggedbottom` works, but because I have a two-sided document I'd prefor not to use it. (I found documentation on it in chapter 2 of the KOMA scrguide.)
@DavidCarlisle, you're right, the table on the next page was not in a floating environment. Now it is. This pulls the next section header up (the header alone) so that this header is now the last line hanging around the middle of the page. It still does not look good, but this is another question.

Comment: It is hard to know what this is because there is no MWE.

Comment: latex never breaks the page after a section heading unless you have added code to force that but as you have shown no code it is impossible to guess what is wrong with your code.

Comment: It's quite an effort to produce a minimal working example but I'm really interested now. Can you help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412762/25599