# Section header is alone at the bottom of a page

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, wrapfigure

A section header stands alone at the bottom of a page; its first paragraph is on the next page. The paragraph contains a wrapfigure. What's wrong?

I know there are similar questions but I'd like to know what's exactly the problem in this example. Hint: It can be fixed with `\usepackage[nobottomtitles*]{titlesec}` but it feels like a work-around.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Technische Daten}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Eigenschaft & Wert\\
\hline
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\section{Entsorgungshinweis}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}  % https://placehold.it/71x91
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Skillmon OK thanks, I edited as suggested:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle still you criticism stays valid. It is not our job to transform every provided code into MWEs.

Comment: unrelated to the question but you should never load `inputec` with luatex, and in almost all case `luatextra` is not recommended other than `fontspec` luatextra mostly just loads legacy deprecated packages.

Comment: The usual solution is to just add a \newpage whenever you see a problem.  \pagebreak[3] generally won't do anything.  You can use the needspace package, but you will have to first compute the size of the \section and the image.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle, I didn't know that. Yes, I use lualatex.

Comment: Normally latex never breaks after a section head but the contortions that wrapfig needs to do disables that so in that case you may need to give it some help.

Answer (score 1):

Since `\section` will not normally break before the next paragraph (`\@nobreaktrue`), one could put my version of `\needspace` as the next paragraph.  I threw in another `\@afterheading` to stop the indentation of the next paragraph.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\prewrapfig}[1]% #1 = graphic
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{#1}%
  \dimen0 = \dimexpr \ht0+\dp0+2\intextsep+\baselineskip\relax
  \rule{0pt}{\dimen0}\vspace{\dimexpr-\parskip-\dimen0}\par
\egroup\@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Technische Daten}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Eigenschaft & Wert\\
\hline
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
xxxx & xxxx\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

%\vspace{-4\baselineskip}

\section{Entsorgungshinweis}

\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}%
\prewrapfig{\usebox0}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\usebox0  % https://placehold.it/71x91
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks John, but this is not a solution for me. The content is generated. I still can insert extra LaTeX code, but then I would go with simple solutions like \newpage or \usepackage[nobottomtitles*]{titlesec}. \newpage is still a bad solution for me as it destroys the layout when the content changes (i.e. more paragraphs added above).

Comment: It occurred to me that one should be able to reserve the space AFTER section.  The needspace package won't do it, but my version using \rule and \vspace will.